# need to retrieve records for the last 3 years in sub tasks

Tags: oracle

I need to retrieve the records from some tables with following condition
`BETWEEN SYSDATE-1095 AND SYSDATE` in an `SSIS` package which connects to an Oracle database. however, the data flow task is hanging with this statement. when I tried replacing this line with `BETWEEN SYSDATE-50 AND SYSDATE`, it worked fine.

I want to break the data flow task into several tasks and replace the above line of code in each of the tasks such that I cover the 3 years records. Can you please assist. Will these following lines be correct if I replace them in each of the data flow tasks?

```
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-100 AND SYSDATE -- data flow task1
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-200 AND SYSDATE+100 --data flow task2
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-300 AND SYSDATE+200 --etc
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-400 AND SYSDATE+300
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-500 AND SYSDATE+400
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-600 AND SYSDATE+500
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-700 AND SYSDATE+600
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-800 AND SYSDATE+700
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-900 AND SYSDATE+800
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-1000 AND SYSDATE+900
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-1095 AND SYSDATE+1000
AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE BETWEEN SYSDATE-1096 AND SYSDATE+1095
```

Comment: Hanging? Or just very very slow? I think the last one, which makes sense if your plowing through years of data... It doesn't make sense either. The last condition implicitly also makes all the other true.. `SYSDATE+1095` is also something you might reconsider. Do you actually have future data? If not, I think the better check would be using `AND LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE >= sysdate - 1096`. A check like that should be trivial if you have a proper index, although you may still get a huge result set, which would explain the slowness.

Comment: Are there other processes using the database at the same time?  If your plan is to run a dozen queries simultaneously, that could reasonably be expected to put a fair amount of load on the server and might negatively affect other users.  I'm also hard-pressed to imagine why you'd want to use the number of days to go back 3 years-- that will either be 1095 or 1096 days depending on when you run the code.  Using `add_months` would make much more sense.  Your intervals are also wrong-- presumably all the `+ 100` should be replaced with `- 100`. But then you're counting `sysdate-100` in two tasks.

Comment: Is `LAB.DETAIL_SVC_DATE` an indexed column? If not, adding an index *might* help.